# How to do template pack expansion with C++11 attribute-list?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

According to [[temp.variadic#5.8]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.variadic#5.8):

> Pack expansions can occur in the following contexts:
>
> - In an *attribute-list* ([dcl.attr.grammar]); the pattern is an *attribute*.

which means we can do a pack expansion on [*attribute-list*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes).

But I didn’t find any examples about it, and [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) only showed a piece of code for it:

```
void [[attributes...]] function()
```

Under what circumstances do we want to do this? And how to do this? Can someone give an example?

Comment: Just speculating: `[[MyCompiler::unused(attributes)...]]` ?

Comment: @MSalters. The *parameter pack* comes from the *template-list*, but where do the `attributes` come from?

Comment: Just to clarify: the name `attributes` in that example is just an example. It still requires that `attributes` is a _ parameter pack_. Presumably, for the `[[MyCompiler::unused(args)...]]` case, that would be from something like `template<class ...Ts> void f(Ts... args) [[MyCompiler::unused(args)...]]`